# Please tell me the passive of this

Tags: passive-voice

> How many people will you invite for your daughter's wedding?
>
> How many people will be invited for your daughter's wedding?

Is this correct form of passive?

Comment: Your sentences are perfect, except for: one say invite someone TO a wedding, not for. They were invited TO the party. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is localized, and an AMIRITE question whose answer is unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

> How many people will you invite to your daughter's wedding?

This is a correct active sentence. The subject (you) does the action (will invite).

> How many people will be invited to your daughter's wedding?

This is a correct passive sentence. The subject (people) is acted upon by the verb (will be invited).

Comment: No, not invite for. Invite TO your daughter's wedding.